# locally complete intersection subschemes on AG surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an arithmetically Gorenstein surface in $\mathbb P^3$ and $Z$ be a zero-dimensional locally complete intersection subschme on $X$. Then is it true in general that any non-empty subscheme of $Z$ is also locally complete intersection?

If the answer to this question is negative in general, then can we locate those subschemes of $Z$ which are again locally complete intersections ( e.g. what about those subschemes which fails to impose independent conditions on $\mathcal O(d)$, for some $d$ or say satisfies Cayley Bacharach property for some $\mathcal O(d)$, in these situation is there a way to construct a rank $2$ bundle and in turn show that those subschemes are locally complete intersection)

any remark from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Are the subschemes you consider open subschemes, closed subschemes?

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez, closed.

Answer (score 2):

No. Moreover, for any zero-dimensional subscheme $Z \subset X$ there is an lci zero dimensional subscheme $Z' \subset X$ such that $Z \subset Z'$.

Comment: Is there a way to know which subschemes are locally complete intersection type ( does there exists a more precise characterization result?)

Comment: If $Z \subset X$ is a zero-dimensional subscheme supported (set-theoretically) at point $x \in X$ then $\dim \mathrm{Tor}_i(\mathcal{O}_Z,\mathcal{O}_x) = \binom{2}{i}$.